# How to use FileSystemWatcher for synchronizing two folders action's

Tags: c#, .net, directory, synchronization

So,i have a task :
Sync content of the 2 dirs in real time
Given the paths of the 2 dirs,listen for changes in dir1 and synchronize the actions with dir2.This means that when i create a new file in dir1,the same file should be in dir2,the same happens when i delete or modify the file.Dir1 may have nested folders.
I have this starting point:

```
public class Program2
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sourcePath = @"C:\Users\artio\Desktop\FASassignment\root\dir1";
        string destinationPath = @"C:\Users\artio\Desktop\FASassignment\root\dir2";

        var source = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
        var destination = new DirectoryInfo(destinationPath);

        using var sourceWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(sourcePath);

        sourceWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
                             | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
                             | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
                             | NotifyFilters.FileName
                             | NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                             | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                             | NotifyFilters.Security
                             | NotifyFilters.Size;

        sourceWatcher.Changed += OnChanged;
        sourceWatcher.Created += OnCreated;
        sourceWatcher.Deleted += OnDeleted;
        sourceWatcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;
        sourceWatcher.Error += OnError;

        sourceWatcher.Filter = "*.txt";
        sourceWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        sourceWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangeType != WatcherChangeTypes.Changed)
        {
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Changed: {e.FullPath}");
    }

    private static void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        string value = $"Created: {e.FullPath}";
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }

    private static void OnDeleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) =>
        Console.WriteLine($"Deleted: {e.FullPath}");

    private static void OnRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Renamed:");
        Console.WriteLine($"    Old: {e.OldFullPath}");
        Console.WriteLine($"    New: {e.FullPath}");
    }

    private static void OnError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e) =>
        PrintException(e.GetException());

    private static void PrintException(Exception? ex)
    {
        if (ex != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Message: {ex.Message}");
            Console.WriteLine("Stacktrace:");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            Console.WriteLine();
            PrintException(ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
}
```

In the `onCreated` event i have added this line :
File.Copy(e.FullPath, destination);

and it created the file if it was in main dir, but if it was in a nested folder, it threw an error. Then i tried to add this code in the event:

```
FileInfo destFile = new FileInfo(destinationFolder + srcFile.FullName.Replace(sourceFolder, ""));

if (!Directory.Exists(destFile.DirectoryName) && createFolders)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(destFile.DirectoryName);
}

//Check if src file was modified and modify the destination file
if (srcFile.LastWriteTime > destFile.LastWriteTime || !destFile.Exists)
{
    File.Copy(srcFile.FullName, destFile.FullName, true);
}
```

Also, didn't work. What should i do to get this task done? I'm learning c# and i dont know all the details,thanks in advance!

Comment: @TimSchmelter The process cannot access the file because it it being used by another process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have completed this task,but remains a little problem in this program,when i try to create a subfolder in the dir1,it gives unauthorized exception that i dont have access to the subfolder path,i think i combine them not in the good way,but i dont know how to fix it.Now,the program mirror the actions from dir1 in dir2,without subfolders.

```
public class Program2
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sourcePath = @"C:\Users\artio\Desktop\FASassignment\root\dir1";
        string destinationPath = @"C:\Users\artio\Desktop\FASassignment\root\dir2";

        var source = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
        var destination = new DirectoryInfo(destinationPath);

        using var sourceWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(sourcePath);

        sourceWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
                             | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
                             | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
                             | NotifyFilters.FileName
                             | NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                             | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                             | NotifyFilters.Security
                             | NotifyFilters.Size;

        sourceWatcher.Changed += OnChanged;
        sourceWatcher.Created += OnCreated;
        sourceWatcher.Deleted += OnDeleted;
        sourceWatcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;
        sourceWatcher.Error += OnError;

        sourceWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        sourceWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangeType != WatcherChangeTypes.Changed)
        {
            return;
        }
        string destinationPath = @"C:\Users\artio\Desktop\FASassignment\root\dir2";
        var fullPath = e.FullPath;
        var name = e?.Name;
        string destination = Path.Combine(destinationPath, name);
        File.Copy(fullPath, destination, true);
        Console.WriteLine($"Changed: {e.FullPath}");
    }

    private static void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        string value = $"Created: {e.FullPath}";

        var Destination = @"C:\Users\artio\Desktop\FASassignment\root\dir2";
        var name = e.Name;
        var fullPath = e.FullPath;
        string destination = Path.Combine(Destination, name);
        Console.WriteLine($"Copy to: {destination}");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        File.Copy(fullPath, destination, true);
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }

    private static void OnDeleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Deleted: {e.FullPath}");

        var name = e.Name;
        string destinationPath = @"C:\Users\artio\Desktop\FASassignment\root\dir2";
        string destination = Path.Combine(destinationPath, name);
        File.Delete(destination);
    }

    private static void OnRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Renamed:");
        Console.WriteLine($"    Old: {e.OldFullPath}");
        Console.WriteLine($"    New: {e.FullPath}");

        var oldFileName = Path.GetFileName(e.OldFullPath);
        var newFileName = Path.GetFileName(e.FullPath);
        var Destination = @"C:\Users\artio\Desktop\FASassignment\root\dir2";
        var oldDestinationPath = Path.Combine(Destination, oldFileName);
        var newDestinationPath = Path.Combine(Destination, newFileName);
        var info = new FileInfo(oldDestinationPath);
        info.MoveTo(newDestinationPath);
    }

    private static void OnError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e) =>
        PrintException(e.GetException());

    private static void PrintException(Exception? ex)
    {
        if (ex != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Message: {ex.Message}");
            Console.WriteLine("Stacktrace:");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            Console.WriteLine();
            PrintException(ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
}
```